# Extracting number from Open Weather Map API get_temperature() string in Python

Tags: python, string, api, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project in which I want my RPi to, after detecting movement with a PIR sensor, turn on an LED and play a song. This is to simulate a "Smart home" system. The type of song that'll be played is going to depend on the outside temperature.

To get the outside temperature into my program I've used the free [Open Weath Map API](http://openweathermap.org/api), the problem is that the function used to return this data, the get_temperature() function, returns the following string:

```
weather.get_temperature('celsius') #returns: {'temp_max': 10.5, 'temp': 9.7, 'temp_min': 9.0}
```

I want to extract the part that comes after **'temp':** in this case being **9.7** because I want to use this value to determine what song I'm going to play.

Hopefully one of you guys knows how to get this done because it's the last thing needed to complete my program!

Thanks in advance,
Job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_temperature` returns a `dict` with temperature info. You can get value from dict for the given key.

```
temperature = weather.get_temperature('celsius')
temp_value = temperature.get('temp')
```